# convert MooTools js script to jquery

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have been struggling to get this right! Can anyone help me to convert this piece of MooTools js script to jquery? The script is a dynamic query constructor. The live implementation is in http://opl.bibliocommons.com/search.

The script I need to convert is below. I can understand what this script is doing, but I don't know the equivalent jquery functions which can do the same job. Any pointers on how to approach this is appreciated.

```
var AdvancedSearch = new Class({
    Implements: [Options],
    options: {
        disable_form_message: "Editing this field means you won't be able to use the constructor form. Continue?"
    },
    initialize: function (instance, options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.instance = $(instance);
        this.query_chunks = this.instance.getElements('div.query_chunk');
        this.not_chunks = this.instance.getElements('div.not_chunk');

        this.instance.addEvent('submit', this.do_search.bindWithEvent(this));

        this.term_count = this.query_chunks.length;
        this.not_term_count = this.not_chunks.length;

        this.query_field = $('custom_query');
        if ($('custom_edit').value == 'false') {
            this.query_field.removeEvents('focus');
            this.query_field.addEvent('focus', this.disable_form_elements.bindWithEvent(this));
        }

        this.operation = $('operator');
        if (this.operation) {
            this.operation.addEvent('change', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
        }


        this.query_chunks.each(function (el, i) {
            el.getElement('select.parameter').addEvent('change', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
            el.getElement('input.operand').addEvent('keyup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
            el.getElement('input.operand').addEvent('mouseup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
            el.getElement('a.remove_btn').removeEvents('click');
            el.getElement('a.remove_btn').addEvent('click', this.remove_query_part.bindWithEvent(this));
        } .bind(this));

        this.add_keywords = $('add_query_part');

        if (this.add_keywords) {
            this.add_keywords.addEvent('click', this.add_query_part.bindWithEvent(this));
        }
        this.not_chunks.each(function (el, i) {
            el.getElement('select.not_parameter').addEvent('change', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
            el.getElement('input.not_operand').addEvent('keyup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
            el.getElement('input.not_operand').addEvent('mouseup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
            el.getElement('a.not_remove_btn').removeEvents('click');
            el.getElement('a.not_remove_btn').addEvent('click', this.remove_not_part.bindWithEvent(this));
        } .bind(this));


        this.add_not_keywords = $('add_not_part');

        if (this.add_not_keywords) {
            this.add_not_keywords.addEvent('click', this.add_not_part.bindWithEvent(this));
        }

    },

    add_query_part: function (ev) {
        if (ev) ev.stop();
        this.query_chunks[0].addClass('removable');
        var query_chunk = this.query_chunks[0].clone().set({ 'class': 'query_chunk query_piece', 'id': "query_chunk_" + (++this.term_count) }).inject($('query_parts'));
        var search_param_select = query_chunk.getElement('select').set({
            'class': 'parameter',
            'id': 'parameter_' + this.term_count,
            'style': 'margin-right:3px'
        });
        var keyword = query_chunk.getElement('input[type=text]').set({
            'class': 'operand text',
            'id': 'keyword_' + (this.term_count),
            'style': 'margin-right:3px',
            'value': ''
        });
        var remove_btn = query_chunk.getElement('a').set({
            'class': 'remove_btn',
            'id': 'remove_' + (this.term_count)
        });
        $("query_chunk_" + this.term_count).addClass('removable');
        this.query_chunks.push(query_chunk);
        remove_btn.addEvent('click', this.remove_query_part.bindWithEvent(this));
        keyword.addEvent('keyup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
        keyword.addEvent('mouseup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
        search_param_select.addEvent('change', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
        return query_chunk;
    },


    remove_query_part: function (ev) {
        ev.stop();
        var remove_index = ev.target.getParent('div').id.split("_")[2];
        this.query_chunks.splice(this.query_chunks.indexOf($('query_chunk_' + remove_index)), 1);
        if ($('query_chunk_' + remove_index)) {
            $('query_chunk_' + remove_index).dispose();
        }
        this.construct_query();
        if (this.query_chunks.length == 1) this.query_chunks[0].removeClass('removable');
    },


    add_not_part: function (ev) {
        if (ev) ev.stop();
        this.not_chunks[0].addClass('removable');
        var query_chunk = this.not_chunks[0].clone().set({ 'class': 'not_chunk query_piece', 'id': 'not_chunk_' + (++this.not_term_count) }).inject($('not_parts'));
        var search_param_select = query_chunk.getElement('select').set({ 'class': 'not_parameter', 'id': "not_parameter_" + (this.not_term_count), 'style': 'margin-right:3px' });
        var keyword = query_chunk.getElement('input[type=text]').set({ 'class': 'not_operand text', 'id': 'not_keyword_' + (this.not_term_count), 'style': 'margin-right:3px', 'value': '' });
        var remove_btn = query_chunk.getElement('a').set({
            'class': 'not_remove_btn',
            'id': 'not_remove_' + (this.not_term_count)
        });
        $("not_chunk_" + this.not_term_count).addClass('removable');
        this.not_chunks.push(query_chunk);
        remove_btn.addEvent('click', this.remove_not_part.bindWithEvent(this));
        keyword.addEvent('keyup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
        keyword.addEvent('mouseup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
        search_param_select.addEvent('change', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
        return query_chunk;
    },


    remove_not_part: function (ev) {
        ev.stop();
        var remove_index = ev.target.getParent('div').id.split("_")[2];
        this.not_chunks.splice(this.not_chunks.indexOf($('not_chunk_' + remove_index)), 1);
        $('not_chunk_' + remove_index).dispose();
        this.construct_query();
        if (this.not_chunks.length == 1) this.not_chunks[0].removeClass('removable');
    },

    disable_form_elements: function (ev) {
        if (confirm(this.options.disable_form_message)) {
            disable_form(this);
        } else {
            ev.stop();
            $('advanced_search').getElement('div.queryBox').getElements('input')[1].focus();
        }
    },


    construct_query: function (ev) {
        Messages.clear();
        var query_string = "";
        var part_pattern = "{param}({keyword})";
        var not_pattern = "-{param}({keyword})";
        var operation_pattern = "{operation}";

        if (this.query_chunks.length > 1) {
            query_string += "(";
        }
        var operands = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.query_chunks.length; i++) {
            if (this.query_chunks[i].getElement('input.operand').value != "") {
                var myObject = {
                    param: (this.query_chunks[i].getElement('select.parameter').value != "anywhere") ? this.query_chunks[i].getElement('select.parameter').value + ":" : "",
                    keyword: this.query_chunks[i].getElement('input.operand').value
                };
                operands.push(part_pattern.substitute(myObject));
            }
        }
        query_string += operands.join(" " + this.operation.value + " ");
        if (this.query_chunks.length > 1) {
            query_string += ")";
        }

        var not_operands = new Array();
        for (var j = 0; j < this.not_chunks.length; j++) {
            if (this.not_chunks[j].getElement('input.not_operand').value != "") {
                myObject = {
                    param: (this.not_chunks[j].getElement('select.not_parameter').value != "anywhere") ? this.not_chunks[j].getElement('select.not_parameter').value + ":" : "",
                    keyword: this.not_chunks[j].getElement('input.not_operand').value
                };
                not_operands.push(not_pattern.substitute(myObject));
            }
        }
        if (query_string != "") query_string += " ";
        query_string += not_operands.join(" ");


        if (query_string != "") query_string += " ";
        query_string.trim();
        this.query_field.value = query_string;
    }
});

function disable_form(o)
{
    o.query_field.removeEvents('focus');
  $('custom_edit').value = 'true';
  $('advanced_search').getElement('div.queryConstructor').addClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: Ouch. Pay me and I'll think about it.  :)

Comment: you can keep the class if you use http://www.moo4q.com/ but you will need to replace all dom access code with the jquery syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may well be better off looking at what the script does and reimplementing it after having "grokked" jQuery.

But if you want to translate...

The first challenge you'll have is that jQuery doesn't have an analogue of the `Class` feature of MooTools. I've done an implementation of `Class` that's very similar to Prototype's (which MooTools' was based on) except I add a feature to make supercalls *dramatically* more efficient; it's in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html) which you could probably adapt. You'll have to translates the `Implements` thing (fairly certain that just becomes a superclass parameter to my equivalent).

Then:

- The fundamental difference is that MooTools *extends* element instances, but jQuery *wraps* them. All jQuery instances are basically enhanced array-like things, where the instance you're interacting with acts a bit like a set, but you can index to the actual underlying DOM element(s) via `[]` (e.g., in jQuery, `var list = $('.xyz');` gives you a jQuery instance, `list`, which has a `length` and can be indexed into via `[]` (`list[0]` is the first underlying raw DOM element). So, anywhere you're accessing the raw properties of a DOM element on the MooTools-enhanced instance (e.g., something you got back from `$` or `$$`), either find the jQuery equivalent function or index into the jQuery object to get at the raw DOM instance. For instance, in the above, if I want the ID of the first match in `list`, I'd do either `list.attr('id')` or (knowing me) more likely `list[0].id`.
- `$('foo')` becomes `$('#foo')` (or `$(document.getElementById('foo'))`, but that's awkward). (Only when it's a string [note the quotes]; when it's a DOM object, leave it — hence the second form.)
- `$$` becomes `$`.
- `getElements` and `getElement` both become `find`. (jQuery doesn't really have a concept of individual wrapped elements, just a jQuery instance with only one element inside it.)
- `addEvent` becomes `bind`.
- `removeEvents` becomes `unbind`.
- `bind` becomes `proxy`.
- jQuery doesn't have a direct analog of `bindWithEvent`, but you're probably okay with `proxy` for where you're using it. Double-check that you get the arguments in the order you expect.
- `.value` becomes `.val()`.
- `set` probably becomes `attr`, but with class names use `addClass` instead.

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive review of this "question." However, the OP needs to be fully aware that simply swapping methods will lead to many dead ends and headaches, and that he should truly try to "grok" what jQuery AND MooTools is doing.

Comment: @Crowder: Thanks. It helps. I understand its a long script, but your answer will help me get started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to cut the class up into smaller chunks and tackle problems one at a time?

Also leave the mootools functionality in as you convert, and instead of $() use "jQuery()"

example

```
    function disable_form_jquery(o)
    {
      jQuery(o.query_field).unbind('focus');
      jQuery('#custom_edit').val('true');
      jQuery('#advanced_search').children('div.queryConstructor').addClass('hide');
    }
```